# Disabling memory consuming gifs in eww mode

Tags: eww

I am looking for a way to disable or remove aspects of a page which might too memory intensive. For instance [this page](https://blackboxofpm.com/ruthless-prioritization-e4256e3520a9) when opened in eww readable mode has a gif which hogs a lot of the memory.

Is there a way to disable the gif at the top of the page or even to remove parts of the page?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed!

Add the following to your `init.el`: `(setq shr-image-animate nil)`.

Comment: Works splendidly! Thank you! :D